# WinError 10054 with socket module upon exit

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Well, the title says it all..

I have a simple server:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ("", 5453)
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    while True:
        data = connection.recv(16)

        if data:
            print(data.decode())

        connection.close()
        break
```

And a simple client:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ("localhost", 7171)
sock.connect(server_address)

while True:
    given_text= input("Enter your text: ")
    sock.sendall(str.encode(given_text))

    data = sock.recv(16)
    print(data.decode())
```

Thing is, if the client closes the connection before typing a text, the server crashes with the error:

```
  data = connection.recv(16)
  ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client didn't close the connection. It exited *without* closing the connection, which caused Windows to *reset* the connection. Solution: close it properly. But the server always has to be able to cope with connection resets.

Comment: Yep, you are right about exitting without closing. But I tried creating an atexit function to close the socket whenever the client exits but it didn't work too.

Comment: It ran as if nothing happened and the same error happened. The function was basically a "return sock.close()".

Comment: So did the `atexit()` function execute? and if so did the close succeed?

Comment: Yep, it did execute. I made sure to check it. And well, if it did obtain any success I guess the error wouldn't occur, would it? I've got no idea if the socket actually closed...

Comment: So **debug it!** Check the return value. Mostly likely it was WSAEINVAL, i.e. you didn't close the correct socket handle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness, sir. I managed to make it work just like you said.